# Create Multikey in sub Document mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a structure like this

```
{
   "myid" : "x47ccv1",
   "info" : [ 
       {
           "id" : 0.0000000000000000,           
           "op" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "dc" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "lt" : [ 
               ""string",
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
           ],
           "enable" : true
       },
       {
           "id" : 1.0000000000000000,           
           "op" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "dc" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "lt" : [ 
               ""string",
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
           ],
           "enable" : false
       },
       {
           "id" : 2.0000000000000000,           
           "op" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "dc" : [ 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 

           ],
           "lt" : [ 
               ""string",
               "string", 
               "string", 
               "string", 
           ],
           "enable" : true
       }
       ...and so on
   ]
}
```

I Want for example to take all elements dc string or only dc string when enable is false.
I create an aggregate query like:

```
db.coll.aggregate([

{
    $unwind:"$info"
},
{
    $match:{"info.enable":false}
},{
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        "info":{$push:"$steps.dc"},
        "tot":{$sum:1}
    }
}

])
```

It work but it is slow ( 7 sec ), because I have 120000 documents.
I tried also to create key on info, but I have this error

```
    "err" : "Btree::insert: key too large to index ....
```

I tried also create key on db.coll.ensureIndex({"info.success":1}), But I have the same result ( 7 sec)

Do I have change the structure or can I optimize this query?

Comment: try moving the `$match` operation above the `$unwind`. It should be there after the unwind too. Also try adding a `$redact` stage, which would keep only the sub documents which have `enable` as false, before the `$unwind`.

Comment: @BatScream thanks, with `$match` above `$unwind` I have `aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`

Comment: Do you have an index on info.enable ? And can you try adding a redact stage after the first match and before the unwind.

Comment: @BatScream Yes I have the key on `info.enable` and I try the Redact after first match and before the unwind but I have `aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)`. I think that my model is not good, because, array inside another array isn't easy to manage, but create two collection isn't a performant, because I have two query anytime.